# Did Proto-Slavic allow four syllables with yers to be consecutive?

Tags: slavic-languages

On another forum, we were discussing my proposal (presented in [a paper I published in Valpovački Godišnjak and Regionalne Studije in 2022](https://flatassembler.github.io/Karasica.doc)) that the river name Karašica comes from Illyrian *Kurrurrissia, borrowed into Proto-Slavic as *Kъrъrьsьja which would give "Karaš-ica" in modern Croatian by regular sound changes:
[image]
Somebody said that they think that Proto-Slavic phonotactics didn't allow four consecutive syllables with yers as vowels (as in *Kъrъrьsьja). So, is that true? There clearly are a few few words with three consecutive syllables with yers, such as *dьnьsь (today).

Comment: Even if there were such a rule which I doubt it applies only for native words but not for borrowings.

Comment: @SirCornflakes doesn't this just depend on whether it's an accidental gap or an active phonotactic prohibition? The former can certainly fail to apply to loans (cf initial p in Germanic), and it'd be very tricky to tell which category such a PSl rule was in

Comment: My understanding is a yer is very short, which is why they have been elided in many descendant languages. Given this, I would expect an even number of adjacent yer syllables to display some apocope of each iamb, and consequent reanalysis as a sequence of closed syllables

Comment: @OmarandLorraine >> consequent reanalysis as a sequence of closed syllables << You realize Proto-Slavic didn't have closed syllables, right?

Comment: @FlatAssembler, I have heard such a thing, but I won't commit to saying whether it's true or not. But but: read my previous comment carefully again and you will see that I meant that the "reanalysis as a sequence of closed syllables" happened "consequently", i.e. in "many descendant languages", not in Proto-Slavic.